# Disable input on check/uncheck of checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes and 2 input tags for mail and phone.

My requirement is such that I want to disable the input of phone when I check mail and vice-versa. But on checking both the checkboxes I want to keep both the inputs enabled.

Here's my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/myphpontest/rhr43g4m/). This is the code which is not working on the fiddle as I've never used it before. But it is working on my localhost.

The problem is, it's not working well when I check both boxes and then check-unchek many times.

**HTML**

```
<input type="checkbox" id="check_email" name="check_email" onchange="disablePhone()" /> Email
<input type="checkbox" id="check_phone" name="check_phone" onchange="disableEmail()" /> Phone
```

**Script**

```
var chk_mail = 0;
var chk_phone = 0;
var unchk = 0;

function disablePhone()
{
    if(unchk == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("ref_email").disabled = true;
        unchk = 0;
        //alert("disablePhone")
    }
    if(chk_mail == 0 && unchk == 0)
    {
        if(document.getElementById("check_email").checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById("form-field-phone").disabled = true;
            chk_mail = 1;
        }
    }
    else if( chk_mail == 1 && unchk == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("check_email").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("form-field-phone").disabled = false;
        chk_mail = 0;
    }
    if(chk_phone ==1 && chk_mail == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("ref_email").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("form-field-phone").disabled = false;
        chk_phone = 0;
        unchk = 1;
    }
}

function disableEmail()
{
    if(unchk == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("form-field-phone").disabled = true;
        unchk = 0;
        //alert("disableEmail")
    }

    if(chk_phone == 0 && unchk == 0)
    {
        if(document.getElementById("check_phone").checked == true)
        {
            document.getElementById("ref_email").disabled = true;
            chk_phone = 1;
        }
    }
    else if(chk_phone == 1 && unchk == 0)
    {
        document.getElementById("check_phone").checked = false;
        document.getElementById("ref_email").disabled = false;
        chk_phone = 0;
    }
    if(chk_phone ==1 && chk_mail == 1)
    {
        document.getElementById("ref_email").disabled = false;
        document.getElementById("form-field-phone").disabled = false;
        chk_phone = 0;
        unchk = 1;
    }       
}
```

Comment: get out of the inline event declaration ages! way too old!

Comment: Your code does well in my native browser. I think may be there is something wrong with JSFiddle compatibility.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added `eventlisteners` in the JS and altered the logics a bit. The script fist checks if both boxes are checked. It true, then make both fields enabled. If not disable the right field.

```js
(function() {
    document.getElementById('check_email').addEventListener('change', disableInput, false);
    document.getElementById('check_phone').addEventListener('change', disableInput, false);
    function disableInput() {
        var emailChecked = document.getElementById('check_email');
        var phoneChecked = document.getElementById('check_phone');
        var email = document.getElementById('ref_email');
        var phone = document.getElementById('form-field-phone');
        
        if(emailChecked.checked == phoneChecked.checked) {
            email.disabled = false;
            phone.disabled = false;
        } else if(emailChecked.checked) {
            phone.disabled = true;
        } else {
            email.disabled = true;
        }
    }
})();
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check_email" name="check_email" /> Email
<input type="checkbox" id="check_phone" name="check_phone" /> Phone
<br>
<input type="email" id="ref_email"  name="ref_email" placeholder="Email ID" />
<input type="text" id="form-field-phone" name="form-field-phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
```

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that my code is in php, so addEventListener won't work. Right?

Comment: @Akshay I'm using `addEventListener` on my PHP page and it is working fine.

Comment: @Akshay If you do not want to use `eventlisteners` you could change your code's `onchange` and remove the `eventlisteners`.

Answer (score 1):

The below code is the solution for you issue .

[fiddle here - Working perfect](http://jsfiddle.net/chintansoni/jn5souhc/) 
 - JavaScript

`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#check_email").click(function () {
            call();
        });
        $("#check_phone").click(function () {
            call();
        });
        function call() {
            document.getElementById("form-field-phone").disabled = false;
            document.getElementById("ref_email").disabled = false;
            if ($("#check_email").is(':checked') && $("#check_phone").is(':checked')) {
                document.getElementById("form-field-phone").disabled = false;
                document.getElementById("ref_email").disabled = false;
            }
            else {
                if ($("#check_email").is(':checked')) {
                    document.getElementById("form-field-phone").disabled = true;
                    document.getElementById("ref_email").disabled = false;
                }
                if ($("#check_phone").is(':checked')) {
                    document.getElementById("form-field-phone").disabled = false;
                    document.getElementById("ref_email").disabled = true;
                }
            }
        }
    });
    </script>
```

`

Comment: You should not be using jQuery in your answer if the question isn't tagged with jQuery.

Comment: @Afsa - What is wrong if user adapt new technology or technology up-gradation ?

Comment: Hey thanks by the way, it's also working. I don't mind implementing it with jquery.

Comment: @user Not all websites can implement jQuery for different reasons. It is nothing wrong to adapt to new tech. However, here on SO the general rule is `"Unless a tag for a framework or library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected for questions with the javascript tag."`

Answer (score 0):

I test this on JSFiddle and I find that isn't work! But In the SOF Editor. It works! 
Your code haven't bug. Maybe it's JSFiddle defect.

```js
function checkDisable(){
  var checkEmail = document.getElementById('check_email');
  var checkPhone = document.getElementById('check_phone');
  var inputEmail = document.getElementById('ref_email');
  var inputPhone = document.getElementById('form-field-phone');
  if(checkEmail.checked){
   inputPhone.disabled = true;
  }
  if(checkPhone.checked){
   inputEmail.disabled = true;
  }
  if(checkEmail.checked && checkPhone.checked){
   inputEmail.disabled = false;
   inputPhone.disabled = false;
  }
  if(!checkEmail.checked && !checkPhone.checked){
   inputEmail.disabled = false;
   inputPhone.disabled = false;
  }
 }
```

```html
<input type="checkbox" id="check_email"  name="check_email" onchange="checkDisable()" />
 Email
 <input type="checkbox" id="check_phone" name="check_phone" onchange="checkDisable()" />
 Phone
 <br>
 <input type="email" id="ref_email"  name="ref_email" placeholder="Email ID" />
 <input type="text" id="form-field-phone" name="form-field-phone" placeholder="Phone"/>
```